# SQL Server - Select all records whose dates are within 5 days of target date

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: Select *]

I need to create a view everyday with all records reaching the "Prazo" date ('Prazo' stands for due date in Portuguese), so everyday I need to make a select showing all the records that are 5 days from reaching the due date. How can I do that?

Comment: `DATEDIFF()` is a good start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
Select *
from Table as t
Where DATEDIFF(DD, GETDATE(), PrazoDate) = 5
```

It just says how many records from today are 5 days from reaching their due date.